# error: Adapter content issue

Tags: android, listview

Please advice what the problem is with my code.???

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131296324, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.platinumapps.platinumtasks.ActionsAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1556)
at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run(AbsListView.java:2868)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check you tried to change adapter in non-UI thread

Comment: if possible please provide the code of adapter and code where data of adapter is changed and where you notified data is changed to adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Handlers`,`UI-threads` or `AsyncTask` (postexecute) to call `notifydatasetchanged();`.
You are doing it in background thread...

Answer (score 0):

Call [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) inside below, put this inside a thread

```
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    // call it here
                 }  
             }
```